# JQuery to get input field value based on label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to copy the value of the first input box to the second input box.  The id and name of these input boxes are coming from tables.  What is fix will be the labels like 'Code' and 'Copy Code'

```
<label>Code</label>
<input type="text" value="1234"  id="custcode_1" />

<label>Copy Code</label>
<input type="text" value=""  id="custcode_2" />
```

For normal scenario it will be just

```
$('#custcode_2').val($('#custcode_1').val());
```

But the id or name are generated on the fly so this is not possible.  How to achieve this using labels of the input boxes.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `for` attributes on your labels....!

Comment: thanks sure will do.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can store the data value at data- attributes:

```
<label id="code" data-value="1234">
<label id="copy_code" data-value="">
```

and then copy the value of code to copy_code using

```
$('#copy_code').data('value', $('#code').data('value'))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but fields are generated dynamically so were the labels.   label id's are coming from db as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the inputs and in this loop grab the previous input of the current one. From there you take it's value.

```js
$('input').each(function(i, e) {
  var previousSibling = $(this).prevAll('input').first();
  
  if (previousSibling.length) {
    $(this).val(previousSibling.val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Code</label>
<input type="text" value="1234" id="custcode_1" />

<label>Copy Code</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="custcode_2" />
```

Comment: I think this is really close, but fields are not in order.   actually i have a checkbox that will copy a set of fields (more or less like 5 fields) let say billing address fields to shipping address fields.    To be specific like copying a value from text box with label "Billing Address"  to "Shipping Address" and so on.

Comment: There's nothing you can input in your data to correlate the two somehow? If not it seems pretty impossible to determine.

Comment: I was hoping a jquery to get the value of the nearest or sibling input field text box with the given label

Comment: So in the above case what would the two have in common?

Comment: Since labels are not changing I can use that like 'Billing Address' to 'Shipping Address'

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the elements in a span or div with a class and then use that as your scope.

```
<span class="custWrapper">
<label>Code</label>
<input type="text" value="1234"  id="custcode_1" />

<label>Copy Code</label>
<input type="text" value=""  id="custcode_2" />
</span>

$('.custWrapper').on('load', function(){
    var inpts = $(this).find('input');

    $(inpts[1]).val($(inpts[0]).val());
});
```

Comment: Field and labels id's are generated on the fly.  It will changed if I do migration on another server.   What wont change is the labels.  Please see my original question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this after giving `id` for both the label's.

**HTML:**

```
<label id='Code'>Code</label>
<input type="text" value="1234"  id="custcode_1" />

<label id='CopyCode'>Copy Code</label>
<input type="text" value=""  id="custcode_2" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function(){

$('label').text('Copy Code').next('input[type=text]').val($('label').text('Code').next('input[type=text]').val());

});
```

Comment: Thanks Hrishi, but as mention only the label values like 'Code' and 'Copy Code' are not changing.  Input textboxes and label id's are coming from database.   I cannot put a fix id on label or input fields because if we migrate to another database the id won't be the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```
//Find the input textbox with label Code
var $copy = $('label').filter(function () {
    return this.firstChild.nodeValue.trim() === 'Code';
}).next('input');

//Find the input textbox with label Copy Code
var $copycode = $('label').filter(function () {
    return this.firstChild.nodeValue.trim() === 'Copy Code';
}).next('input');

//Copy the value
$copycode.val($copy.val());

//Copy the value as character typed into the textbox
$('input').on('keyup',function(){
$copycode.val($copy.val());
});
```